# Pygame midi Different velocity in left and right channel

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, midi

Using Pygame.midi libaray, we can play note with the midi.note_on(self, note, velocity, channel=0) method:

For example:

```
pygame.midi.init()
player = pygame.midi.Output(0)
player.set_instrument(0)
player.note_on(64, 127)
time.sleep(1)
player.note_off(64, 127)
del player
pygame.midi.quit()
```

However, I need to play the sound at different velocity on my left and right channel to create some spatial effect. Using it seems that I can't achieve this with player.note_on(64, 127). Is there any alternatives? Basically I am looking for some APIs like:
player.note_on(64, left_velocity=127, right_velocity=100). I would need the support for different instrunments.

If pygame can't achieve this effect, is there any other libaray that can do this?

Comment: [ac](file:///C:/my%20C/Finance/)

Answer (score 0):

The MIDI specifications says:

> A Pan Controller has been adopted as continuous controller number 10 (0AH)
> with value 00 = hard left, 64 (40H) = center, and 127 (7FH) = hard right. This
> controller determines where a single sound source will be located in a stereo
> field.

Synthesizers that claim conformance to General MIDI Level 1 must support this controller.